# Is it possible to get the Instagram profile picture and other basic details?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get the details of the user using the `access_token` from the `Instagram APIs`, `Instagram Basic Display API` and `Instagram Graph API`. What I found is the details are bit messy and by going deep into it I'm not able to conclude the final result as I want.

What I got to know during the implementation is that Instagram has stopped the public APIs. does that mean apart from getting `auth-token` then had stopped everything?.

I have even tried the `Instagram Basic Display API` which is only giving the access of 4 fields `account_type`, `id`, `media_count`, `username`. Is it possible to get any other field from the same API?

If so How do I get the profile picture of the user and other basic details of the Instagram user?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the API endpoint for retrieving a user's profile information only allows for the retrieval of the 4 fields you listed above. This is, up to now, all that has been made available for retrieval through the `me` endpoint of the [Instagram Basic Display API for getting a User node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user).

Until the API developers further extend the API's endpoints and capabilities, you won't be able to use this API programmatically to get a user's profile image.